# PHP $_FILES multiple file uploading problem

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload

I have a little problem with uploading multiple files in PHP ,

i have this html form:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"  />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and this is the upload.php :

```
<?php print_r( $_FILES ); ?>
```

when i'm sending a file it show me this:

```
 Array
(
[myfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Krw_Qe4QKmI.mp3
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

 )
```

so far so good.

the problem starts when i upgrade my form to this one :

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"  />
    <input type="file" name="myfile[]"  />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

now , when i send 2 files , it show me this :

```
Array
(
)
```

so , what's the problem here?
thank you , Mor.

Comment: You have an error in the first array you show (with the code `1`). See here for what it means: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of suggestions here. I'll give it a go. This is based on @Pekka 's comment.

I see you're testing with mp3s, which probably exceed PHP upload limit. This is because in your first example, you actually have an upload error code 1: `The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`. So even your fist upload didn't work. A successful upload always has 0 as the error code.

Modify you php.ini with `upload_max_filesize = 10M` (or `20M`, or `300M`; careful about that `M` - which means *megabytes* - as omitted, brings alot of headache.

I suggest testing with smaller files, as I see you have a limit of 2M for uploading.

[**Further reading**](http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapUpload/wap_upload.asp?page=php2).

Answer (score 2):

I would bet that you exceeded [`post_max_size`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and PHP just ignored the uploaded files.

It's 8MB by default. If you try to upload one 5MB file everything will work. If you try to upload 2 5MB files, it exceeeds 8MB and PHP ignores posted data.

Try increasing the value of post_max_size in your php.ini.

Comment: enable [log_errors](http://php.net/log_errors) and look at your server's error_log

Comment: im checking now , so far i can see if i upload 2 small files it works but with bigger files it wont

Comment: i run my code on WAMP 2 32 bit , this is what's on my ini

    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    ; File Uploads ;
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    ; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
    ; http://php.net/file-uploads
    file_uploads = On

    ; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
    ; specified).
    ; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
    upload_tmp_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"

    ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
    ; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
    upload_max_filesize = 2M

Answer (score 1):

Check your [`max_file_uploads`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) setting -- is it more than 1?

```
echo ini_get('max_file_uploads');
```

Comment: i did run this command but nothing came up , i also checked in the ini file it self it does not have such a thing

Answer (score 0):

The php.ini file must have something like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M


; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Change the values of `upload_max_filesize` and then restart the server

Comment: i dont have the max_file_uploads part on my ini file , can you tell me which system you work with and download link to you're ini file?

Comment: @Mor you need to modify your own php.ini, it's no good downloading somebody else's

Comment: that's weird, you can copy & paste the code in you php.ini file and this is the content of the [php.ini recommend](http://pastebin.com/QAebhauV) I have php 5.2.17

Answer (score 0):

To do multiple files at once, try giving an index like this:

```
<? For ( $count = 0; count < SOME_MAXIMUM; ++$count; ): ?>
<input type="file" name="myfile[<? Echo $count; ?>]"  />
<? endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. All my efforts were in vain, but finally I found a pretty good note at the PHP Manual. It's simple but suited me perfectly...

> "Multiple upload might not work if you use a table for displaying your
>   form inputs when `<form>` element is ***inside*** the `<table>` element. In this
>   case **only the first file will be uploaded**.
>
> Put the  `<form>`  element **outside** the  element to get it to work."

Follow this link for the full note, there is a function to rearrange the multiple upload file array in a easy-to-use manner.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score -1):

The Problem is your `name="myfile[]"` attribute on your input-Element.

You cant referer later in PHP to your file, if you haven't an identifier for it. The PHP-Documentation gives you the same hint:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

> Multiple files can be uploaded using different name for input.

So change the name to "myfile1" and "myfile2" (or some better name ;)) should solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, you *can* upload multiple files having the same input name, just like OP used: `name[]`.