# PHP $_FILES - Last file of multiple file only uploading

Tags: php, file

My problem is very similar to
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463538/php-files-multiple-file-uploading-problem)

I tried my level best and at last, I'm posting my query here. Hope to get a solution for the below problem.

**Problem**
I'm trying to upload multiple files through php.
But getting one file in $_FILES array.

**Other meta data**

1. php.ini config. file_uploads = On
2. php.ini config. upload_max_filesize = 2M
3. php.ini config. max_file_uploads = 20
4. PHP version 8
5. No error in error log

**index.html**

```js
//^Ajax to upload file
function jx_ajax_upload_file(xData) {
     return $.ajax({
     url: "php.php",
     type: "post",
     data: xData,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     async: true,
     });
   }
//Ajax Error Message
function error() {
    console.log("connection error");
}

 // Submit Button
 document.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", () => {
 let loadedFiles = document.querySelector("#los").files;
 let filesCount = loadedFiles.length;
 if (filesCount == 0) return;
 
 var dataToPhp = new FormData();
 for (let i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
  dataToPhp.append("xxx", loadedFiles[i]);
 }
 jx_ajax_upload_file(dataToPhp).done(los_helper).fail(error);

 function los_helper(data) {
  console.log(data);
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Multi File Upload</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="los" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**php.php**

```
<?php
print_r ($_FILES);
?>
```

Comment: When adding the files to the form, try adding with `"xxx" + i` to give each file a unique name.

Comment: Thank you Nigel Ren. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
dataToPhp.append("xxx", loadedFiles[i]);
```

each file is given the same name, one alternative is to add the index to the field name...

```
dataToPhp.append("xxx" + i, loadedFiles[i]);
```